# how to use dynamic extension php.ini in laravel class file

Tags: php, laravel, apache-kafka

i have been learning about kafka and laravel.

so i'm trying to implement kafka(using rdkafka) in laravel, but i have a problem

when i tried to use kafka in php, everything works fine in pure php, but i got an error when i tried to implement it in laravel as a command class

```
$conf = new RdKafka\Conf();
```

i think that's the problem, 
RdKafka is a dynamic extension in php.ini(i added it manually directly from php.ini) and become undefined when i tried to implement in laravel and i don't know how to solve it.

how to use dynamic extension in laravel?

here is the command class and consumer function tutorial from rdkafka

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ExampleCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:name';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
        $conf = new RdKafka\Conf();


        $conf->set('group.id', 'myConsumerGroup');

        $rk = new RdKafka\Consumer($conf);
        $rk->addBrokers("127.0.0.1");

        $topicConf = new RdKafka\TopicConf();

        $topicConf->set('auto.commit.interval.ms', 100);
        $topicConf->set('offset.store.method', 'file');
        $topicConf->set('offset.store.path', sys_get_temp_dir());


        $topicConf->set('auto.offset.reset', 'smallest');

        $topic = $rk->newTopic("test", $topicConf);


        $topic->consumeStart(0, RD_KAFKA_OFFSET_STORED);

        while (true) {
            $message = $topic->consume(0, 120*10000);
            switch ($message->err) {
                case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR:
                    var_dump($message);
                    break;
                case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__PARTITION_EOF:
                    echo "No more messages; will wait for more\n";
                    break;
                case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__TIMED_OUT:
                    echo "Timed out\n";
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new \Exception($message->errstr(), $message->err);
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

error that i got from artisan command

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
Class 'App\Console\Commands\RdKafka\Conf' not found
```

Comment: You need to import namespace or start with '\', it tries to find class in your current namespace.

Comment: RdKafka doesn't exist in any directory in my project folder and it comes from php.ini. when i try the code in pure php, i don't need to include any directory of RdKafka, it just works

Comment: did your pure php script use namespaces and autoloading?

Comment: I don't tell you need to include directory, just use leading slash or import namespace (`use` statement). http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php

Comment: hi man, i'm using  `use \RdKafka` at top and my kafka is working right know. thanks a lot @MateuszSip

Comment: glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

I am using PHPStorm and had the same problem with the IDE recognizing the namespace.  I finally found out that I needed to install the stubs for the IDE to recognize the extension namespaces.  The extension actually works though (\RdKafka).  It's just that the IDE didn't recognize the namespace until I installed the stubs.

https://github.com/kwn/php-rdkafka-stubs

Answer (score 0):

The problem you didn't Add this line to using namespaces so the package namespace will be like this `App\Console\Commands\RdKafka\Conf` and this is wrong so you should add the below line in using namespaces:

```
 namespace App\Console\Commands;
 use Illuminate\Console\Command;
 using RdKafka\Conf; // Add this line
```